# Redirect more than one page to a single page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, hyperlink

I need to redirect more than one page to a one single page. In particular I'd need all the pages with this structure:

`www.mywebsite.com/PAGE1/something1
www.mywebsite.com/PAGE1/something2
www.mywebsite.com/PAGE1/something3...`

to be redirected to www.mywebsite.com/PAGE2.
Is this possible? My website uses wordpress (if it could be useful).
Thank you in anticipation

Comment: Welcome to the site. 

Plese read **"How to ask a question"** tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 

The questions of type "I need this ... " without telling what are you did to fix the problem should not be accepted.
What did you tried to solve the problem? Have you tried to search somewhere? If yes, please provide the information found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htaccess to get what you want

```
Redirect /PAGE1 http://mywebsite.com/PAGE2/
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention an essential thing. I don't know in advance which links I'm going to redirect.
The only thing I know is that they are of this type:
www.mywebsite/PAGE1/andthensomething...
So, i need to redirect ALL the links with /PAGE1/

Comment: Well that is it...

- Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html /path/to/new/file/new.html -

Here is reference
https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489